# Running WebJobs on Azure Emulator

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-emulator

I'm trying to getting Webjobs to run locally, with the Azure emulator, but it's generating an exception. I only found old posts (from early 2015) of saying the Azure emulator does not support local execution due to some unsupported Blob functionality. I wonder if this limitation is still valid or if there exists some workaround?

When running locally I'm creating the JobHostConfiguration as:

```
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
config.StorageConnectionString =  "UseDevelopmentStorage=true";   
config.DashboardConnectionString = "UseDevelopmentStorage=true";
```

Upon initialization I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 
Failed to validate    Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK Storage account.
```

Any idea of how to get WebJobs to execute locally? Any known work arounds? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if this limitation is still valid or if there exists some workaround?

The short answer is yes. If you want to work with Webjobs, you need to interact with a valid storage account.

That doesn't mean that you can't execute them locally though. You can always stop your Webjob that's running in the cloud and run the same Webjob from your machine.

Comment: @Niclas I know, hopefully this gets fixed on a later release.

Comment: Related [feedback item](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/7334594-support-web-jobs-running-locally-on-the-storage-em) and [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/53)

Comment: I have the same issue. Can seem to use Web Jobs with the Azure SDK Emulator which is a bummer